# How different clauses treat Null/Unknow in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, null

(relatively new to SQL and SQL Server)
I am reading *SQL Server 2012 T-SQL Fundamentals* by Itzik Ben-Gan. Autor states that:

> SQL has different treatments for UNKNOWN in different language
>   elements

So, I went through SQL Server documentation, and in particular [`WHERE` clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx), but could not find anything specific on how `NULL/UNKNOWN` is treated.

Could someone point me to correct document or point me to what I am reading wrong in the documentation ? (I highly suspect that answer to my question is buried deep somewhere in the SQL Standard, but it might be way too complex for me, at least at this point.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are subtle differences on how `UNKNOWN` and `NULL` are treated in the various clauses.

Three clauses where a boolean expression can appear are the `WHERE`, `HAVING` and `FROM` (in the `ON` sub-clause). In all three, the `UNKNOWN` is treated the same way.

- `WHERE <boolean expression>`:

  a row "passes" the `<boolean expression>` and is returned if the expression evaluates to `TRUE`. If the expression evaluates to `FALSE` or `UNKNOWN`, the row does not pass and is removed from further evaluation of the query.
- `HAVING <boolean expression>`:

  The rows examined in the `HAVING` clause are those created by the aggregation of the previous `GROUP BY` clause. Similar to above a row (created by the aggregation) "passes" the `<boolean expression>` and is returned if the expression evaluates to `TRUE`. If the expression evaluates to `FALSE` or `UNKNOWN`, the row does not pass and is removed from further evaluation of the query.
- `a JOIN b ON <boolean expression>`:

  Every row from `a` is checked against every row from `b`. If the expression is `TRUE`, then the check passes and the combination of the two rows is valid for further processing of the query. If `FALSE` or `UNKNOWN`, then the combination is rejected.
  There is a slight change when the join is an outer join (`LEFT`, `RIGHT` or `FULL`) but not regarding how `UNKNOWN` is treated. What happens here is that if a row from the left table (in a `LEFT` join) matches no row from the right table (i.e. all its checks evaluate to `FALSE` or `UNKNOWN`), then this row is still forwarded and the missing values for the `b` columns are filled with nulls.)

The situation is different in the constraints, there is a more "relaxed" treatment for `UNKNOWN`. I guess this has to do with the decision of allowing nulls in the first place. A null value will result in an `UNKNOWN` result in most constraints, so it makes sense to allow those rows to be inserted. Otherwise, the effect would be the same as declaring the columns as `NOT NULL`.

- `CHECK` constraint: `CHECK <expression>`

  a row is allowed to be inserted (or updated) if the expression evaluates to `TRUE` **or** to `UNKNOWN`. It is rejected only if the expression evaluates to `FALSE`.
- `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, with nullable columns.

  similar to the check constraints, if a row has a null in one of the columns that participate in a foreign key constraint, the verification of the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint is skipped and the row is allowed to be inserted (or updated.) One can think of a foreign key constraint in table `a`:

  ```
  FOREIGN KEY (column) REFERENCES b (column)
  ```

  to be equivalent to:

  ```
  CHECK (column IN (SELECT column IN b))
  ```

  So, if `a.column` is `NULL`, the expression is evaluated to `UNKNOWN` and thus the row is allowed.
- `UNIQUE` constraints

  Here SQL-Server deviates from the standard which state that if a row with a unique constraint contains `NULL`, then the unique check is skipped and the row is allowed.
  SQL-Server treats nulls as if they were regular values, when it comes to unique constraints and allows **only one `NULL` value**, in such columns.

---

`NULL` values have also special treatment in some clauses:

- `GROUP BY`:

  If a grouping column contains null values, all null values are considered equal, and they are put into a single group (the same thing happens in a `SELECT DISTINCT` query.)

  Aggregate functions (`MIN()`, `MAX()`, `SUM()`, `AVG()` and others) ignore nulls with the exception of `COUNT()` which can do a lot of different things:

  - `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(constant)` will count all rows.
  - `COUNT(column)` and `COUNT(expression)` will ignore nulls as the other aggregate functions and count only rows where the column or expression is not null.
  - `COUNT(DISTINCT column)` and `COUNT(DISTINCT expression)` will also ignore nulls and count only the distinct non-null columns or expressions.

  So the following 4 queries may return 4 different results if there are nulls in the column:

  ```
     SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t ;
     SELECT COUNT(c) FROM t ;
     SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c) FROM t ;
     SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT c FROM t) AS x ;
  ```
- `ORDER BY`:

  - In comparisons between them, `NULL` values are treated as equal.
  - When comparing them to non-null values, null values are treated as the lowest possible value, lower than any non-null value. As a result, they appear first when the order is `ASC` and last when the order is `DESC`.
    (There is a `NULLS LAST` and `NULLS FIRST` attribute defined in the latest standard but SQL Server has not implemented it yet.)